# Need to get a 360 view of the object using cameras

Tags: camera

I need to render an object and get a 360 degree view. I plan to do this by taking pictures from atleast 36 cameras, at 10 degree separation to give a 360 degree view.

Since I have several objects, I dont want to this manually. I am thinking to write a script to do it.

Is there any better alternative to do it, other than writing a script? Some way if I can do it manually in a much faster way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

### Animate a single camera

Parent your camera to an empty placed in the rotation pivot point.

[image]

Now the camera should follow the rotation of his parent object using its origin as pivot.

Than insert two keyframe to the empty's Z-rotation channel in 0,0 and in 36,360 to animate the rotation through time.

[image]

Remember to set the interpolation mode of your keyframes to linear if you want a constant angular velocity and to set the final render frame range to 35 as the 36th is the same as the first.

[image]

Set png, jpeg ... an image, non video, format in the output tab and than pressing Render Animation button you'll get each frame rendered individually.

*Note: if it is suitable for your scene, you can also think about rotating the object(s), instead of the camera.*

Comment: You should either render from frame 0 to 35 or from frame 1 to 36.